# How to send mail with attachment

Tags: php, forms, attachment

Using form on web site, I want to upload attachment first and send it to arbitary email address. I've tried to use phpmailer, but I've never managed to attach file just browsing it, only directly:

```
$mail->attachment("images/hello.jpg");
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem, or any alternative solution to PHPMailer?

Comment: [swiftmailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org) is one alternative. But, even with that, you will want to transfer the file up to your PHP script, process it, then attach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this on the server processing ought to work:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] <= 0 ){ // success, no error

    // read in the contents of temporary file
    $file_contents = file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );

    // add the contents to phpmailer object, with original filename from upload
    $mail->addStringAttachment( $file_contents, $_FILES['file']['name'] );
}
```

This assumes your form element is named `file`, like:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I have another question, do you know how to add a progress bar which would indicate level of upload, or that is a complete new level? Would that include use of AJAX? And do you have  some link where I could find something about it?

Comment: That's another level. It's possible to some degree in PHP 5.4 (see http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php), but other solutions probably work better. Like https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you'll need to create an upload form, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for more information on that. After uploading the file it can be attached to a mail just as you did in your example. The file name is then replaced by the path and file name where you saved the upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, from http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script :

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Good answer, but the OP is using the `PHPMailer` class which abstracts much of the work you've shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you need to use the AddAttachment() instead of attachment()?

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
```

You may also have to make sure that the path to the file is correct in relation to your script on the server.

From https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer